# Changing/Adding the Caption label

Tags: captions

I wanted to have a new caption label "Plate 1", "Plate 2".... and so on.
In addition, the same document should have figure and table captions also.
That means I need "Plate 1", "Plate 2"...., "Figure 1", "Figure 2"...., "Table 1", "Table 2"....

Comment: Welcome :) // Can you please provide code, we can copy and run, which shows your problem? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried any code. But I referred https://latex-tutorial.com/caption-customization-latex/.
The solution I need was not described in there.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Dear DG, Thank you for the effort. The problem has been solved by Miyase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with two packages: `caption` to provide the ability to switch between two 'sorts" of caption labels, and `newfloat` to provide the ability to create a custom caption label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{plate}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{\label{fig:image}An image.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\captionsetup{type=plate}
\caption{\label{fig:plate}A plate.}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you Miyase. It worked perfectly.