# How to create an environment like "Figure" for inserting algorithms in a LaTeX paper?

Tags: floats

As running algorithms with "algorithm2e" gives a compatibility problem for me (with a journal LaTeX style), I am running "algorithm2e" in a standalone environment and using the outputs like "algorithm1.pdf", "algorithm2.pdf" with "\includegraphics" command.

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=140mm,width=90mm]{Figures/Algorithm2.pdf}
 \end{center}
```

This gives me an alignment problem in LaTeX output. Either the algorithm is cramped or paper looks in an awkward manner.. If I use "figure", then Algorithm gets a Figure number.. I like to know if we can create a Figure-like enviroment which can be used like Figures, but when we run, we get "Algorithm 1 : ....", "Algorithm 2 : " with the captions.

Thanks for your great help!

Best wishes
Sundar

Comment: See the newfloat and/or float packages for creating new float types.

Comment: @Dr. Sundar: A quick search could have given you [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644647/changing-adding-the-caption-label/644648#644648), which uses `newfloat` as @JohnKormylo suggested.